# c++ Undefined references in PNG although png.h included

Tags: c++, cmake, png, homebrew

I am trying to compile [Libviso2](http://www.cvlibs.net/software/libviso/). Even though the `png.h` is included, there are errors about undeclared identifier png. I am not sure what is wrong here?

The demo code in it goes something like

```
#include <png.h>
...
...
png::image< png::gray_pixel > left_img(left_img_file_name);
```

My CMakeLists.txt goes as follows

```
# project
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (libviso2)

find_package(PNG REQUIRED)

# directories
set (LIBVISO2_SRC_DIR src)

# include directory
include_directories(${PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories("${LIBVISO2_SRC_DIR}")

link_directories(${PNG_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PNG_DEFINITIONS})

# use sse3 instruction set
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-msse3")

# sources
FILE(GLOB LIBVISO2_SRC_FILES "src/*.cpp")

# make release version
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

# demo program
add_executable(viso2 ${LIBVISO2_SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries (viso2 ${PNG_LIBRARY})
```

Upon `cmake ../ && make` it throws me bunch of errors related to png references not found

```
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/viso2.dir/src/demo.cpp.o
/Users/pranav/workspace/libviso2/src/demo.cpp:80:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'png'
      png::image< png::gray_pixel > left_img(left_img_file_name);
      ^
/Users/pranav/workspace/libviso2/src/demo.cpp:80:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'png'
      png::image< png::gray_pixel > left_img(left_img_file_name);
                  ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`png::` namespace seems to come from [C++ bindings to PNG](http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/), `png++.h` header file. You should install it first.

And some notes regarding CMake code. According to documentation you should use `target_link_libraries (viso2 ${PNG_LIBRARIES})`, you also can remove `link_directories` call, because CMake will figure out needed flags.